# How can I access the full contents of a parallel array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, parallel-arrays

I am trying access the full contents of a parallel array by having the user enter an identification number. The array only seems to return results for the first four items [0-3]. The remainder are returned as not found. Using Eclipse, I tried to fully dimension the array to 10 memory locations, however, I get errors.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class StudentIDArray {
    static String[] studentNum = new String[]
            {"1234", "2345", "3456", "4567", "5678", "6789", "7890", "8901", "9012", "0123"};
    static String[] studentName = new String[]
            {"Peter", "Brian", "Stewie", "Lois", "Chris", "Meg", "Glen", "Joe", "Cleveland", "Morty"};
    static double[] studentGpa = new double[]
            {2.0, 3.25, 4.0, 3.6, 2.26, 3.20, 3.45, 3.8, 3.0, 3.33};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String studentId = null;
        while ((studentId = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your Student ID number to view your name and GPA")) != null) {
            boolean correct = false;
            for (int x = 0; x < studentId.length(); ++x) {
                if (studentId.equals(studentNum[x])) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your name is: " + studentName[x] + "\n" + "Your GPA: " + studentGpa[x], "GPA Results", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    correct = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!correct) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student ID not found, try again.", "Not found", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In the for loop change:

```
studentId.length();
```

to

```
studentNum.length;
```

You are now using the length of the input string while you need to the length of the array.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't you be iterating over the "studenNum" array in your for loop? You have a typo/bug where you are iterating over the wrong variable.

Answer (score 2):

Please look at your `for` loop:

```
for (int x = 0; x < studentId.length(); ++x)
```

Instead of using the length of your `studentNum` array, you're using the length of the user input `studentId` which is most likely 4 characters long (due to your given student ids in `studentNum`). That is why your program only find entries on index 0 - 3 (*The array only seems to return results for the first four items [0-3]*).

Change it to

```
for (int x = 0; x < studentNum.length; ++x)
```

to fix it.